# kth smallest element in two sorted array - O(log n) Solution

Tags: arrays, algorithm, array-merge

The above is one of the interview question. There is an article about 0(log n) algorithm explaining the invariant (i + j = k – 1). I'm having much difficulty in understanding this algorithm. Could anyone explain this algorithm in simple way and also why do they calculate i as (int)((double)m / (m+n) * (k-1)). I appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
 protected static int kthSmallestEasy(int[] A, int aLow, int aLength, int[] B, int bLow, int bLength, int k)
       {
        //Error Handling
        assert(aLow >= 0); assert(bLow >= 0);
        assert(aLength >= 0); assert(bLength >= 0); assert(aLength + bLength >= k);
        int i = (int)((double)((k - 1) * aLength / (aLength + bLength)));
        int j = k - 1 - i;
        int Ai_1 = aLow + i == 0 ? Int32.MinValue : A[aLow + i - 1];
        int Ai = aLow + i == A.Length ? Int32.MaxValue : A[aLow + i];
        int Bj_1 = bLow + j == 0 ? Int32.MinValue : B[bLow + j - 1];
        int Bj = bLow + j == B.Length ? Int32.MaxValue : B[bLow + j];
        if (Bj_1 < Ai && Ai < Bj)
            return Ai;
        else if (Ai_1 < Bj && Bj < Ai)
            return Bj;
        assert(Ai < Bj - 1 || Bj < Ai_1);

        if (Ai < Bj_1) // exclude A[aLow .. i] and A[j..bHigh], k was replaced by k - i - 1
            return kthSmallestEasy(A, aLow + i + 1, aLength - i - 1, B, bLow, j, k - i - 1);
        else // exclude A[i, aHigh] and B[bLow .. j], k was replaced by k - j - 1
            return kthSmallestEasy(A, aLow, i, B, bLow + j + 1, bLength - j - 1, k - j - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Could anyone explain this algorithm in simple way`.

Yes, it is essentially a bisection algorithm.

In successive passes, it moves probes on one array index upward and the other index array downward, seeking equal values while keeping the sum of the two indices equal to *k*.

`and also why do they calculate i as (int)((double)m / (m+n) * (k-1)).`

This gives an estimate of the new half-way point assuming an equidistribution of values between the known points.